# DB2 execute not correlated query too long

Tags: db2

We have this query:

```
select OBJECT_TYPE,
    OBJECT_ID as testname,
    OBJECT_REV,
    XACCESS,
    COPIEDFROM,
    DELETION,FSYSID_TYPE1,FSYSID_1,FSYSID_TYPE2,FSYSID_2 
FROM HPSFWY.RVERSIONING_8220434 A 
WHERE LATEST = 'X' 
    AND coalesce(DELETION,
    ' ') != 'X' 
    AND DTLOCK <= 0 
    AND XACCESS = 0 
    AND COMMITID <= 8 
    AND A.object_id IN (SELECT object_id 
                        FROM HPSFWY.RVERSIONING_7084273
                        WHERE commitid > 8)
ORDER BY 
    OBJECT_ID, OBJECT_REV DESC ;
```

DB2 execute this query too long, looks like it execute subquery for each row. Is it possible to rewrite this query?

Comment: Can you provide an output of the `db2exfmt -d mydbname -1` utility call after `db2 explain all with snapshot for select OBJECT_TYPE, ...`?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hzfU8OKpPEcHo7Adq1L-Kfxv_9luaBsj/view?usp=sharing

We uploaded output to Google Disk. BTW, db2advis doesn't help with indexes. We can use temp table for subquery select and then use temp table in main query , but maybe there is a way to rewrite query without temp tables?

Comment: It it tablescanning RVERSIONING_7084273 . Does that table have a valid  index on OBJECT_ID column?  Does that table have column distribution statistics collected (at least on the commitid column) ?  Test an index on OBJECT_ID with an INCLUDE column for commitID. Use distribution stats.

Comment: Thanks, We will try. In fact, we have indexes, but doesn't have any distribution statistics

Comment: This doesn't help

Comment: @tolyy You should enlarge SORTHEAP significantly. Your current SORTHEAP=1802 is not enough for sorting intermediate results of both tables before MSJOIN. Set it to 30 000 at least. Consider enlarging your bufferpool size as well. The size of 24 878 pages looks not large enough, if it's not some very resource constrained system...

Comment: Thanks, Mark,we did not play with these DB2 settings